# Get row index of a WPF Datagrid row that has cursor in it

Tags: wpf, datagrid

How to get the row index of a `DataGrid` row in WPF that has the keyboard or mouse focus in it. I don't want `DataGrid.SelectedIndex` or `DataGrid.SelectedItem`, Because that returns only -1 when the cell is in edit mode.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this helper method to get the row index:

```
public static class DataGridHelper
{
    static public int GetRowIndex(DataGrid dataGrid, DataGridCellInfo dataGridCellInfo)
    {
        DataGridRow dgrow = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dataGridCellInfo.Item);
        if (dgrow != null)
            return dgrow.GetIndex();

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Use it like this in the appropriate events:

```
int rowIndex = DataGridHelper.GetRowIndex(yourDataGrid, yourDataGrid.SelectedCells[0]);
```

Comment: Thank You so much Eirik !! I'll Try it out so soon.